# python fabric, Iterate through IP list to update servers

Tags: python, linux, terminal, fabric

Hope you can help. Totally new to fabric, know a little python. I'm trying to iterate through an external file of IP's to update 40 odd remote servers.

This isn't working,stops after the first IP.

Terminal command:
      fab -p Password hosts update

```
from fabric.api import env, run, sudo


def hosts():
    env.hosts = open('sat_ip_list', 'r').readlines()


def update():
     sudo('apt-get update -y')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following list of IPs + Fabric script and had no problems running `fab -p <password> hosts uname`:

```
# ip_list.txt
192.168.xxx.x
127.0.0.1:xxxx
174.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx

# fabfile.py
from fabric.api import env, run, sudo

def hosts():
  # Read ip list from ip_list.txt
  env.hosts = open('ip_list.txt', 'r').readlines()

def uname():
  sudo('uname -a')
```

What does your `sat_ip_list` file look like - is it one IP address per line?

Have you tried your script with just a very small number of hosts, like 2-3 IP addresses? Definitely no reason you shouldn't be able to do what you're trying to accomplish, your script basically works for me just as it is.

As a sanity check, you might want to print out the value of `env.hosts`, like so:

```
def hosts():
  env.hosts = open('sat_ip_list', 'r').readlines()
  print('Hosts:', env.hosts)
```

In my case, that results in the following output:

```
me@machine:~$ fab hosts
('Hosts:', ['192.168.xxx.x\n', '127.0.0.1:xxxx\n', '174.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx\n'])
```